# Is it possible to authorize admin service with another user credential?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I would like to write an add-on to GMail via app script that would display some admin directory data.

But I want this add-on to work on a different account than my admin account. For example, I daily use my daily-mail@google.com to check emails, and from time to time I use my admin@google.com account to manage admin stuff.

Is there a way to use the admin service as admin@google.com while being logged as daily-mail@google.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

Assuming that this other user does not have admin privileges, your only option would be to use a service account with domain-wide delegation that impersonates your admin account:

- [Perform Google Workspace Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)

#### Workflow:

1. Create a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account?hl=no#creatinganaccount).
2. Follow [this guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account?hl=no#delegatingauthority) to grant the service account domain-wide delegation, so that it can be used to impersonate any account in your domain: in this case, your account.
3. Import and use the library [OAuth2 for Apps Script](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2) in order to use the service account in your Apps Script project.
4. Use [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) to call your desired API, using the access token from the service account.

#### Code sample:

For example, if you wanted to call Directory API's [users.get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/get) to retrieve data from the user currently executing this, you would do something like this:

```
function getService() {
  const service = OAuth2.createService("Service account")
                    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
                    .setPrivateKey(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY)
                    .setIssuer(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                    .setSubject(IMPERSONATED_EMAIL)
                    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
                    .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
                    .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user')
  return service;
}

function getActiveUserData() {
  const service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    const userKey = Session.getActiveUser();
    const url = `https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/${userKey}`;
    const options = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + service.getAccessToken(),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    }
    const resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    const userData = JSON.parse(resp.getContentText());
    return userData;
  }
}
```